# I tried Bootstrap DateTimePicker in ASP.NET MVC 5 but it's not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I'm really new to ASP.NET MVC even the Web,I tried to build it on VS 2019,this is NOT the .net core project,it's the .NET for Win project,I tried to build a datetimepicker within the text input, so I tried to build to view like the below

```
@model log_viewer.Models.QueryParms

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "QueryLog";
}

<h2>Query</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Query </h4>
    <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.mdno, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.mdno, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.mdno, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.startdate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @*<div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.startdate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.startdate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>*@
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="input-group" id="datetimepicker">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.startdate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datetimepicker form-control" } })
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.startdate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.enddate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @*<div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.enddate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.enddate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>*@
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="input-group" id="datetimepicker">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.enddate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.enddate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        </div>

       <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Summit" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
   }
```

My models are as below

```
public class QueryParms
{
    [DisplayName("Contains Strings")]
    public string mdno { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Begin Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-mm-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime startdate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("End Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-mm-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime enddate { get; set; }
}
```

When I clicked the datetime picker, it just not working, nothing happened

Comment: you have to define the type= "date" input field for worked date time picker.

Comment: Like @Html.EditorFor(model => model.enddate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" ,@type="date"} })

Comment: nope,startdate and enddate is DateTime tho@Neeraj

Comment: but you have to define in HTML too.

Comment: thank you so much @Neeraj it works!!! but it's the order of date is mm/dd/yyyy while I tried was yyyy-mm-dd tho.but really apperciated it

Comment: ok, the wait I will put a working demo here.

Comment: apperciated your helps

Comment: your helped me a lot,its unnecessary to post a demo here @Neeraj

Comment: ok , then you have to use date picker JS and then put this code in <script>$(function () {
    $('#to').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
});</script>